# post image to facebook page

Tags: iphone, facebook, uiimage, social-framework

Im using SocialFramework for posting image to facebook. When i click the button the facebook page is opening. But my need is, i need to share my image to not in my wall, share to following facebook page `https://www.facebook.com/Google`

code:

```
if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {
            SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

            [controller setInitialText:@"My image"];
            [controller addImage:newImage.image];

            [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:Nil];
        }
```

Comment: if u login into ur login details then it must be share ur wall it self...

Comment: Yes. You are correct. But my need is i need to post this image to not my wall? I need to post to some facebook page

Comment: ur using facebook graph api or anything another ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10746221/post-on-friends-facebook-wall-using-graph-api-on-ios   pls check it

Comment: Im using Social.framework API

Comment: okay u can go for that sdk flow u can achieve ..all the best !!!!!!

Comment: I don't want that sdk. I simply integrate my image to friend wall using social.framework API.

Comment: i think it is not possible ? u must be use facebook graph api